# how can i authenticate the whole computer instead of web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, authentication

For the past 2 years we have created 3 desktop application and 2 admin section(web) for one of my client.
Every application uses its own authentication process.
I have merged the authentication process for web in single unit.
But the client wants to have one screen for getting authenticated on desktop application as well as  on website.

he also want to use different browser and the username /password should be asked only once irrespective of browser opend.

I tried to use cookies for web. but every browser has got its own cookies.

Can any one suggest how can i authenticate a user for the whole computer so that authentication information is available to desktop application as well as to website irrespective of the browser being used?

**Edit:**  <strike>As suggested by joe using windows authentication is not possible in my case.
So i created one more table with following column
ip,userid,authenticatedat
when ever a user is authenticated i insert its ip,userid, and time in table.
when ever a non authenticate user comes first i look in the table if the ip is present and authenticatedat is within 30 min i assume user is authenticated and set the session/variable with data required.
This i have checked and found it is working .</strike>

I have found this is not secure.

Comment: Add an answer to your own question and mark it if you're a happy man.

Comment: Regarding your IP solution (even though you've already crossed it out, just want to comment on it) - it's tempting to use IP addresses, but as I'm sure you've found, IP addresses can be re-used. Internally, an IP can be reassigned from one machine to another (DHCP?). In the public internet, anyone coming from the same network will show up on the request as the same IP. Plus they can be spoofed. So IP addresses are pretty much worthless for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication is the only way I know of doing this. Assuming your users are on a domain you control, then their Windows credentials would validate them, and they wouldn't ever need to enter a username and password.

Outside of that, I can only think of hacky dirty methods of making this happen. You could install a single authentication service on their machine which is available to connect to remotely from other applications - those apps would call your service, and that service would authenticate the user and pass an authentication token back. Easy enough for Windows apps, but making that work on a web app wouldn't be fun. Your web server wouldn't be able to talk to this service, so you'd have to rely on the client javascript talking to the service and retrieving a token or hash, and then the javascript passing this on to the web server.

Anything you put on a local machine, you have to assume the user can reverse engineer and manipulate, so if you need real security, I doubt you'll find a solution. Best bet is just to make the user log in every time you need to, and have your authentication/authorization code on your web service layer.